# Why does Google Maps kills my flutter app in the background?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, background-service

We develop a tourism app using flutter, we use Google Maps (map_launcher plugin) to guide the user all over the city. When we Go to Maps, (our app is in background), as soon as we start navigation, our app is killed. No erros, No logs.

I tried to use BackgroundLocation service to keep the app Alive, it works on debug mode ! but not on release.

PS: It's not a memory problem, this does not happen with other memory consuming apps.

Thank you for your Help.

Comment: You haven't given much info to go on. It sounds like your app is crashing when you go to maps. That means, you probably have an unhandled error that crashes the app. You may not see errors/logs because the code to capture them hasn't executed due to the crash.

Comment: I would agree with you on that but what I find bizarre is the fact that the app is not killed when we go to maps, it's killed when the Navigation starts. (Click on Go button)